# How to rename ForeignKey set field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am serializing Foreign key set using Django Rest Framework, I have following models:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    ...
class TransactionStatus(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
    ...
```

I have a serializer for both of these models, one of them looks like this:

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    transactionstatus_set = TransactionStatusSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        depth = 1
        fields = ('id', 'transactionstatus_set')
```

I want to have here a list of transaction statuses from back referenced _set queryset... But transaction_set just seems very awkward name in API for that..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a quick experimenting I have discovered that this will do the trick:

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    changes = TransactionStatusSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='transactionstatus_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        depth = 1
        fields = ('id', 'changes')
```

Now I have a list of the statuses linked by foreign key with a nice name...

Comment: As a note `source` is the original name of the `field` in the `django model`, and the variable that the related serializer is declaring (in this case 'changes') is the final name of the renamed field.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, finding it was killing me